# Deleting a file in Google Script .setTrashed 'You do not have authorization to perform that action.'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a csv file from a Google spreadsheet every day or so. for some reason, I can delete files using the .setTrashed(True) and the file will delete, but i get an error saying 'You do not have authorization to perform that action. '

here is my code. any help would be appreciated.

```
function saveAsCSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  // create a folder from the name of the spreadsheet
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(ss.getName().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_'));
  for (var i = 0 ; i < sheets.length ; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
    fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
    // convert all available sheet data to csv format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
    // update a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data
    var folder = DocsList.getFolder('fitbitdata_mk3'); 
    folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
    deleteDocByName('Sheet1.csv');
    Logger.log('deleted');

    //  folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);   //i put it before the delete



  }
  Browser.msgBox('UPDATED Files are waiting in a folder named ' + folder.getName());
}


function deleteDocByName(fileName){
  var docs=DocsList.find(fileName)
  for(n=0;n<docs.length;++n){
    if(docs[n].getName() == fileName){
      var ID = docs[n].getId()
      DocsList.getFileById(ID).setTrashed(true)
    }
  }
}





function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName, sheet) {
  // get available data range in the spreadsheet
  var activeRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = activeRange.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    // loop through the data in the range and build a string with the csv data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // join each row's columns
        // add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug?  What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: i get the error on DocsList.getFileById(ID).setTrashed(true)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Please star the issue on the issue tracker here.

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4145&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner